# File Path in JavaScript for images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, filepath

This might be the most trivial question but as far as I understand it seems to be correct but I'm unable to view the images as desired. The image shows the file structure and I'm trying to access these from jsGold.js file. It was working fine until I extracted certain files to a new project for cleanup hence I suspect the change in file path may have caused this issue.

[image: File Structure]

Code lines in jsGold.js file:

```
else {
   streamData.push(clickedId, streamName, streamDef);
   var prop = $('<img class="prop" src="../../Images/prop.ico" />').attr('id', i);
   newAgent.text(streamData[nameIndex]).append('<img class="cancel" src="../../Images/delete.ico"/>').append(prop);
```

The output that I'm getting is:

[image: Output]

Desired Output:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: I would expect the `src` path should be relative to the current page in which the JS is running, not to the location of the JS file. So `src="../Images/prop.ico"`.

Comment: The path is relative to the file executing the JS, not the JS file itself. So if your JS file is included in checkon.html, for example, the path would be `../Images/prop.ico`.

Comment: Why don't you use (root) relative URLs i.e. /Images/prop.ico ? This way is easier to read the path and the path is the same regardless of the javascript  / html files location.

Comment: Christophe- Thanks, this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative path of you `img` tag should be relative to the root of your website, not relative to the folder of your script.

You should use :

```
var prop = $('<img class="prop" src="/Images/prop.ico" />').attr('id', i);
```

If you open the page, from `Views`, directly from your disk and not from a webserver, relative path must relative from the `Views` folder. So you have to write it like this:

```
var prop = $('<img class="prop" src="../Images/prop.ico" />').attr('id', i);
```

Comment: *"The relative path of you img tag is relative to the root of your website"* - Not if it starts with `../`.

Comment: Does it depend on the html page where it is loaded?

Comment: @Teja No, because if it starts with a `/` it refers to the root of your website. Now if you open your html pages directly from disk, it's another thing...

Comment: @nnnnnn Typo error. Replaced `is` with `should be`.

Comment: Your second version with `../` should work from a webserver too. But using `/` to go from the root saves having to update paths if you move the html files.

Comment: So I need to only consider which file the browser runs and consider the path in relation to that, right?

Comment: @NayantaraWilfred Yes, it depends on the "context" you are "running" your page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys - the following works since I'm opening the file from work.html in views

```
var prop = $('<img class="prop" src="../Images/prop.ico" />').attr('id', i);
```